# Navbar: Position and background color of the triangles (CSS)

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, responsive

Navbar: Position and background color of the triangles (CSS)

Ok so, I'm trying to create a navigation as shown in the images at the bottom of the page. How can I reach that result? Many thanks in advance.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  line-height: 50px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 1px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-1" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-1" class="label"></label>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-2" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-2" class="label"></label>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-3" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-3" class="label"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image: Navigation 1]

[image: Navigation 2]

Comment: Do you know about pseudo elements, `::before` and `::after`? If you look into how to use these, it can be done, probably with an escaped HTML entity for an arrow down symbol of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon your current code base, you can apply `position: relative` to `<li>` and `position: absolute` to `<label>` to achieve that. Additionaly you need to position your `<label>` using `right: 2.5%` for horizontal positioning and `top: 50%;` with `transform: translateY (-125%);` for vertical centering.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

li {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.label {
  border: solid blue;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(-125%);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  right: 2.5%;
  margin: 1px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-1" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-1" class="label"></label>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-2" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-2" class="label"></label>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 5</a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="dd-3" class="dropdown" />
      <label for="dd-3" class="label"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way is to wrap your chevron in a containing div and position that absolutely relative to each row.

So each row needs:

```
display: flex;
position: relative;
```

You can then position your containing div and centre the chevron easily with:

```
align-items: center;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
```

Here's a pen to get you started: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmmPGy